# How is magnetic flux viewed in QED?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, waveguide

I know that [QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) is formulated in terms of Lagrangian density. So when we solve for a physical system we ultimately ends up finding $\psi$ and $A_{\mu}$. I'm not interested in $\psi$ for now. Since I know $A_{\mu}$ I can calculate $\textbf{B}$ using $\textbf{B}=\nabla\times\textbf{A}$ in Lorenz gauge, of course. After knowing $\textbf{B}$ I can go for magnetic flux, $\Phi=\int\textbf{B}.d\textbf{a}$.

Suppose I'm doing an experiment in a waveguide where quantum effects become dominant (see [this](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.69.062320)) and the variable of interest is $\Phi$ ([physical setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZAad.png)). How can I relate the photon of the radiation propagating in the waveguide with the variable $\Phi$?

Comment: You already did! The magnetic flux operator $\Phi$ can be defined in terms of the magnetic field operator as you wrote, which is in turn defined in terms of the vector potential operator as you wrote.